# Windows 7 64bit ISO can't install in virtual box: Pops up "select driver to install". Why?

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, virtual-machine

Aall three above points are matched with my machine....the problem is that after I boot win7 32bit and 64bit(dual) ISO from virtual box (followed all the required steps to make a virtual disk in Virtual Box), selected "64bit" option to install in virtual box, it pops up a message:

> select driver to install

After selecting the "Browse" option to load pre-os driver it can't access my local hard disk for the driver location. I have downloaded pre-os driver from Dell official website.

I'm not able to go further steps.

My system type is: 32bit operating system of win8.1, having 64bit processor. Dell Latittude E5520, 2GB of RAM.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there are no cross platform duplicates so I will full quote from AskUbuntu:

---

> Virtualbox supports running a 64-bit guest VM on a 32-bit physical
>   host, but there are some requirements and other caveats:
>
> [From the manual:](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch03.html)
>
> > VirtualBox supports 64-bit guest operating systems, even on 32-bit
> >   host operating systems, provided that the following conditions are
> >   met:
>
> - You need a 64-bit processor with hardware virtualization support (see the section called [“Hardware vs. software
>     virtualization”](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch10.html#hwvirt)).
> - You must enable hardware virtualization for the particular VM for which you want 64-bit support; software virtualization is not
>     supported for 64-bit VMs.
> - If you want to use 64-bit guest support on a 32-bit host operating system, you must also select a 64-bit operating system for
>     the particular VM. **Since supporting 64 bits on 32-bit hosts incurs
>     additional overhead, VirtualBox only enables this support upon
>     explicit request.**
>
> **Warning**
>
> - On any host, *you should enable the I/O APIC* for virtual machines that you intend to use in 64-bit mode. This is especially true for
>       64-bit Windows VMs. See the section called ["Advanced"
>       tab](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch03.html#settings-general-advanced).
>       In addition, for 64-bit Windows guests, you should make sure that the
>       VM uses the Intel networking device, since there is no 64-bit driver
>       support for the AMD PCNet card; see the section called [“Virtual
>       networking
>       hardware”](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#nichardware).

[Original Answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/180761/can-i-use-virtualbox-with-a-64-bit-image-in-a-32-bit-host/180764#180764)